# Sending cookies between Flask and javascript and using Flask-session

Tags: javascript, python, flask, session-cookies, fetch-api

I am a web-dev noob but I'll try my best to be clear about the problem, explain my approach, and what I've tried. I also include imports in-case those are causing the problem but I'm pretty sure I've isolated it to what I describe.

I am trying to use Flask-session to keep information private but some values are "lost". This code is trimmed down significantly for simplicity. The user lands on `/send` and we render the loading template. `loading.js` does `fetch()` on `/deploy` while it runs an animation, then() we go to `/results` when the deploy function is done.

loading.js

```
function navigate() {
    window.location.href = 'results';  // redirect to results page when done!
}


 // deploy the contract while the loading screen goes then navigate to results page
const data = fetch('deploy').then(navigate);
  
loopThroughMessages(messages);
```

main.py

```
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__, 
static_folder='static',
template_folder='templates')

# for the session, i.e passing values 
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)


@app.route('/send')
def main():
    # take url parameters and do stuff with them
    return render_template('loading.html')


@app.route("/deploy")
def deploy_contract():
    session['contract_address'] = some_fnc()

    # fetch() requires that this function return a json
    return {} 


@app.route("/results")
def serve_results_page():
    # pull saved values from the session
    data = {'contract_key' : session['contract_address']
    } # calling session here causes the error, the contract_address key doesn't exist

    return render_template('results.html', data=data)
```

So `contract_address` is saved to the session but when we get to `/results`, the server has no way to associate that session with the client.

We want to keep our `contract_address` private so sending it to `loading.js` is not an option. I'm guessing that since `http` is stateless, I need to pass a cookie to and from my js and python files but I'm a bit lost on how to implement it. Are cookies unnecessary (because the server doesn't actually need to receive any data from my js files)? Should I be using redirects or something besides fetch()?

Hacky fixes, different approaches, and resources are all welcome. I feel like I'm close, like there's a simple way to use cookies that I'm overlooking.

I will be continuing to research and detail the approaches I'm considering
Edit1: Looking at Flask's should_set_cookie method

Answer (score 1):

Try `fetch` with [credentials:'include'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) to cause browsers to send a request with credentials included on the server side calls:

```
fetch('deploy', {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include'
}).then(navigate);
```

Using this, you will access `session['contract_address']` in the `results` route.

The `flask-session` sets a cookie with a key session in your browser, fetch with `credentials:'include'`  includes this cookie value in the network call.

Answer (score 0):

Session in flask is implemented as a client session, saving all session content as client cookies. The `flask-session` extension provides some other server storage for session. E.g. `app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"` save session content in a file on the server.

But both of the approaches still depends on `Cookie`. The server-side session storage need to get a `session_id` from client `Cookie`.

You need to enable cookie sending on Fetch API.

[fetch, sending cookies](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies)